Why can't Mathematica compute the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{e^{2n}-1}$?
Why can't Mathematica 14 compute the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{e^{2n}-1}$$
where $\mu$ is the Möbius function? The series is obviously absolutely convergent (summands dominated by $2e^{-2n}$ plus geometric series) and therefore clearly convergent. But Mathematica 14 says this series diverges.
By summation up to $N=1000$ it is $$\sum_{n=1}^{1000} \frac{\mu(n)}{e^{2n}-1}\\ =0.1353352832366126918939994949724844034076315459095758814681588726...
\\ \approx e^{-2}$$ and therefore $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{e^{2n}-1}=e^{-2}$$
should be the value of the series.
Shouldn't Mathematica know that the Möbius function is bounded?
Cross reference to mathematics stackexchange question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4928895

Version 13 returns back unevaluated sum so it is not able to compute it.

Please include Mathematica code in your question. Also, in v14, SumConvergence[MoebiusMu[n]/(Exp[2n]-1), n] stays unevaluated, so I'm not sure how you got it to say that it is divergent ...

Why do you think there is a closed-form expression for this sum? NSum[MoebiusMu[n]/(Exp[2 n] - 1), {n, 1, Infinity}] outputs 0.1353352832366127.

@user64494 Numerically it would seem to extremely close to $e^{-2}$ if not exactly that. Like, more you give NSum chances to compute a high-precision estimate, closer it gets, like $< 10^{-10000}$.

@user64494 I was a bit playing around with Riemann zeta and Gamma function and came to the expression $e^{-t}  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{e^{nt}-1}$ for $t > 0$ and wanted to check some values. Then this happened. And the numerical values seemed that this is probably correct. Now, a proof of this (in some other way I came to the expression) is in the link above explained. I thought Mathematica is able to evaluate this, so this result surprised me!

It is the Lambert series over the Möbius function. There are many others.

you can try
Sum[(MoebiusMu[k]*q^k)/(1 - q^k), {k, 1, Infinity}] /. q -> Exp[-2]
(* 1/E^2 *)


Table[{wp, N[N[Sum[MoebiusMu[n]/(E^(2 n) - 1), {n, 1, Infinity}] - 1/E^2, wp]]}, {wp, 50, 200, 50}] appears to indicate that the difference is constant independent of high precision used, i.e., that they are only approximately equal.

Conversely, Table[NSum[MoebiusMu[n]/(E^(2 n) - 1), {n, 1, Infinity}, NSumTerms -> 175, WorkingPrecision -> wp] - 1/E^2, {wp, 50, 200, 50}] indicates that the difference is zero to high precision.
